# filter data in Spark SQL in Databrick

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks, databricks-sql

When I run below command in Databrick , I get output where I have three columns called name, id and age but when I try to filter on name by running below I get below error as Name column do not exist. What wrong am i doing?

```
%sql
SELECT inline(environment.details) FROM TableA
```

This gives me a table with 3 column correctly.

Now I do filter oon Name like this

```
%sql
    SELECT inline(environment.details) FROM TableA where `Name` == "XYZ"
```

and I get error as Name table do not exist.What wis wrong here. Also if someone can tell me how can I export the resultant output.

Thanks

Comment: what is the type of `environment.details` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filtering happens before your expand your array of structs.  You have two choices here:

1. Use [common table expressions](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-cte.html) to explode first & then filter:

```sql
with exploded as (
  SELECT inline(environment.details) FROM TableA
) 
SELECT * from exploded where name = ....
```

2. Use the [filter](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/filter.html) function to filter out data inside the array with something like that (not tested), but it may require doing the filtering two times:

```sql
SELECT inline(filter(environment.details, x -> x.Name = 'XYZ')) 
FROM TableA 
WHERE array_size(filter(environment.details, x -> x.Name = 'XYZ')) > 0
```

Comment: Nice, I used the first option and thats give me the desired result. I wanted to ask here what if I have to filter on another cloumn as well which are not part of nested environment key. for example the columns which are at same level as environment. and also how do i export the result?

Comment: exporting results - depends on the size of data, etc. For filtering on another column that isn't a part of the nested environment, you may use the 2nd approach. Or add the column into first select of the first approach, and filter on it.

Comment: is there a limit in exporting data ? I am running this command in Azure Databricks.

Comment: it depends if you run it in the notebook or not. If you have a lot of data, you may need to create a table in desired format using `create table using ... as select` - see docs

Comment: For the 2nd option, the where clause could be simplified like this: `WHERE exists(environment.details, x -> x.Name = 'XYZ')`

Comment: yes, but it may depend if we need all environment.details or only matching to the predicate... My variant will return only matching entries, even if array contains not matching

Comment: one question here on using the first option the resultant table has only columns inside environment.details. I would like to get all the fields in table A with the applied filter. how is that possible?

Comment: you need to include them into select, for example refering as `*` or something like. Although in that case, 2nd approach could be better